# Shared Windows-Ubuntu HDD freezing

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Lenovo B50-80 (laptop) with two disks. One 512GiB SSD with Windows 10 and Ubuntu separately installed on it, and one 1TiB HDD used only for data storage. The HDD is installed with a caddy (replacing the dvd reader).

The problem is that the computer completely freezes when I make file operations with the HDD **from Windows**. Something like copying a 200MiB video (from or to the HDD) forces me to restart the system. There's no problem in the Ubuntu side; this only happens when working with windows.

I've been using this disks configuration with this and other laptops for many years. The only difference is that now I'm using windows 10. With Windows 8 / 7 I never found a problem sharing disks between linux and windows. All the information about the partitions are in the next image. I scanned the HDD from Windows and from Ubuntu (with Windows native tool and GParted in Ubuntu) and no problem was found. Fast startup is disabled.

[Partitions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNazW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution ws the obvious one: hard format the drive and from now on never share an NTFS disk between Windows and a Linux distribution.